# `NameError: name column_name is not defined`

Tags: python, pandas

Data frame

```
   uid,api_url
    1, abc.com
    2, xyz.com
```

Code

```
def query():
    jso = {"id": uid,"docs": {"doc1":api_url,"type": "US","advanced": {"details":true}}} 
    json_d = json_dumps(jso)
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    response = requests.post("https://example.net/document",headers=headers,json=json_d)
    return response.text
```

Apply on df
`df['res'] = df[['uid','api_url']].apply(query(),axis = 1)`

`NameError: name 'uid' is not defined`

Below query is working fine while apply on variable and hardcoding `ui_id:'random_number'`

```
def query_api(api_url):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    json_d = {'ui_id': '1111', 'data': {'url': api_url}}
    response = requests.post("http://example.net/v3/doc", 
                             headers=headers, json=json_d)
    return response.text
```

`df['res1'] = df['api_url'].apply(query_api)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an argument for your `query` function

When you call `apply` function what you receive is a `pandas series` and based on the value of your `axis` argument you get `row` or `column`. When you set the value of `axis` to `1` you get a row.

So when you call

```
df['res'] = df[['uid','api_url']].apply(query, axis = 1)
```

you get each row of you dataframe as argument of the query function.

So you need to modify your `query` function to

```
def query(x):
    jso = {"id": x.uid,"docs": {"doc1":x.api_url,"type": "US","advanced": {"details":true}}} 
    json_d = json_dumps(jso)
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    response = requests.post("https://example.net/document",headers=headers,json=json_d)
    return response.text
```

---

Your second case `query_api` works because it has an argument and it will be the column of your data frame.

Hope this explanation helps.

P.S.

In your first `apply` call you have `query()` as argument. I assume that was a typo. You only need to specify the name of the function.

**EDIT**

I have added an example to further explanation

```
>>> df
   uid  api_url
0    1  abc.com
1    2  xyz.com
```

---

```
>>> def query(x):
...     return str(x.uid) + x.api_url

>>> df.apply(query, axis =1)
0    1abc.com
1    2xyz.com
dtype: object
```

Comment: added an example too. and you can just call `df.apply(query, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def query(x):
    jso = {"id": x.uid,"docs": {"doc1":x.api_url,"type": "US","advanced": {"details":true}}} 
    json_d = json_dumps(jso)
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    response = requests.post("https://example.net/document",headers=headers,json=json_d)
    return response.text

df['res'] = df.apply(query,axis = 1)
```